# Check if set of functions is a basis of space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $f_a \in R^R$ be function given by $f_a(x)=1$ if $x=a$ and $f_a(x)=0 $ if $x \neq a$ for $a \in R$

Decide if set of functions $f_a$ is a basis of space of functions $R^R$ ?

I think I know how to show set of $f_a$ is independent. We have $b_1f_{a_1}(x)+ b_2f_{a_2}(x) + ...+ b_n f_{a_n}(x)=0$ and taking for $x$ values from $a_1$ to $a_n$ we obtain $b_1=b_2=...=b_n=0$ so it's independent but I have problem how to check if our set generate all functions $R^R$

Comment: Note you need to check if any given function is a *finite* linear combination of the $f_\alpha$...

Comment: OK, can you give me hint how to check it ?

Comment: Consider a function that takes on infinitely many distinct values.

Comment: for instance $f(x)=x^3$ ? then I have to check if $b_1f_{a_1}(x) \cdot ... \cdot b_n f_{a_n}(x) = x^3$  ??

Comment: Yes. But it's easy to do. Note any finite linear combination of your vectors gives a function that takes on only finitely many distinct values. (So, it's not a basis.)

Comment: I'm wondering how to show what you said: "any finite linear combination of your vectors gives a function that takes on only finitely many distinct values" could you help ? I have to show that linear combination of my functions generate function $A^R$ where $A$ is a finite set, right ?

Comment: I don't think that's quite right.  But, any linear combination of your functions has value zero, except for perhaps a finite number of points. The function $f(x)=x^3$ does not have that property.

Comment: OK but how to argue that linear comb. has a finite number of points ?